# Display console output in django template in real time

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket

I am new to websocket so I have some problems. I'm trying to create a web based user interface, where the user will press the button and start the script in the background and user is redirectet to display_console_output, where data will be displayed. I would like to display console output in the browser in real time. I am able to display the output when the script finished her job, and I do not know how to display data if script is working. Here is my code

views.py:

```
def display_console_output(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        process = subprocess.Popen('ping -t 8.8.8.8', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.communicate()[0]
        return render(request, 'update_file/display_console_output.html', {'page_title': 'Console Output',
                                                                           'console_output': (output.decode('utf-8')),})
```

routing.py:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url(r"^(?P<consoleOutput>[\w.@+-]+)/$", ConsoleDataConsumer),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

I will appreciate if you can give me any advice how to solve my problem..

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible ways are;

1. While the script is running, you can grab and save its output to the database, and in the template, you can send AJAX requests in an interval (say every second) to get the updated console output and display it in the template
2. Setup a websocket server (if you are using django, you can use channels (https://github.com/django/channels) for websockets), establish a websocket connection in your template and push the console outpu in real time to the client side.